# SED; adding # in front of matching line with various special characters

Tags: sed

Okay even though I looked through a ton of posts here and elsewhere, I cannot get a # in front of the following line:

```
[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return
```

I tried several solutions for example:

```
sed -r "s/[ -n '$ID' -a '$ID' -le 200 ] \&\& return/#[ -n '$ID' -a '$ID' -le 200 ] \&\& return/g"
```

and

```
sed 's/[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ]/#&/'
```

And several other ideas based on posts here and elsewhere, but still no result. I only get results like this:

```
[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 #[ -n '0' -a '0' -le 200 ] ] && return] && return return
```

and

```
#if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -o -n "$KSH_VERSION" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
#  [ -x /usr/bin/id ] || return
#  ID=`/usr/bin/id -u`
#  [ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return
#  # for bash and zsh, only if no alias is already set
#  alias vi >/dev/null 2>&1 || alias vi=vim
#fi
```

Maybe someone can explain how I can get a # (hashtag) for that particular line given aboven. Probably it's something simple and my best guess is that I am not escaping things correctly?

As mentioned above, I did look up various posts, but I still cannot seem to get this done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets:

`sed 's/^\[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 \] && return$/#&/'`

Comment: Thank you for explaining, so brackets are also always needed to escape?
I tried your solution, but it does not add an hashtag (#) to that line when I apply it...?

Comment: Nevermind! I fgured it out. Your helpful answer was correct. I didn't take the 2 spaces in front of the file into consideration!! Stupid me. Guess that's also why it never worked before, even though I tried a ton of things.

Note to myself; also take the spaces into consideration next time!

Comment: Yes the `^` at the beginning of the regex would stop it working if there are spaces at the start of your line, but the reason your command didn't work was you had not escaped the `[` and `]`